# What mean path to the icon in *.desktop file?

Tags: 14.04, .desktop

I have installed VSCode in Ubuntu.
I wanna change icon. For this I go to the `/usr/share/applications/` and try change `Visual Code Studio.desktop` with content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Visual Studio Code
Comment=Code Editing. Redefined.
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=/usr/share/code/code --no-sandbox --unity-launch %F
Icon=com.visualstudio.code
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Code
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;Development;IDE;
MimeType=text/plain;inode/directory;
Actions=new-empty-window;
Keywords=vscode;

X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.23

[Desktop Action new-empty-window]
Name=New Empty Window
Exec=/usr/share/code/code --no-sandbox --new-window %F
Icon=com.visualstudio.code
```

What mean path to the icon like this `Icon=com.visualstudio.code`? How change the icon?

Comment: The normal icon is in /usr/share/pixmaps/com.visualstudio.code.png. Just drop another .png file into the same place, and then edit the .desktop icon= lines (there are two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current icon reference, `com.visualstudio.code`, only specifies the name of the icon. The system accordingly will look in default locations (`~/.icons`, `~/local/share/icons`, `/usr/share/pixmaps`, icon folders of current icon themes, ...) for a graphics file with that name and the extension `png` or `svg` or `xpm`. Instead, you can also specify the full file path of a specific icon file to unambiguously define the icon, even if you change icon themes, as in (hypothetical example):

```
Icon=/home/user/.local/share/icons/com.visualstudio.code.png
```

You need to make sure the icon file is readable by all intended users if you specify a full file path.

Comment: The problem with this method is, what if a different "user" tries to start VSCode, they'll get a permissions error as the icon file is in another user's directory path, and/or the icon will not be visible.

Comment: Good remark, I will add this caveat in the answer.